# Cannot run ./start_slaves.sh for spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, ssh

I'm in aws EMR,

```
Master:172.31.1.172
slave1:172.31.1.11
slave2:172.31.1.245
```

I have configured `/etc/hosts`:[image]

Then `${SPARKPATH}/conf/spark-env.sh` file:
[image]

Then `${SPARKPATH}/conf/slaves.template` file:

[image]

And `${SPARKPATH}/conf/workers` file

[image]

I have configured `ssh` to allow master direct connection without any password at:

```
root@slave1
root@slave2
```

However when I'm trying `./start-slaves.sh`, I have the output below:

[image]

In `start_all.sh` `start-master.sh` run without problem, but not for `start-slaves.sh`.

[image]

It seems to be mind by the ssh connection, yet I can run `ssh root@slave1` and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have to follow these steps:

-Connection to super user with
`su`
Then:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

It will create id_rsa.pub in /root/.ssh/

Then, copy /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to authorized_hosts of your localhost:

```
cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_hosts
```

if `ssh localhost`  is passwordless you have succeeded